# Debugview keep logging

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I currently play around with Firebase Analytics.

I find that my DebugView will **keep logging event** after **DELETEING** arguments in scheme. Neither does [--FIRDebugDisabled](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382?hl=en&utm_id=ad&authuser=0) work, any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have double dashes (--). The right one should be *-FIRDebugDisabled*

You can also stop Analytics from debugging by using this flag  *-noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled*